# Generate Asp.net MVC Model from the form fields dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am building a Web Application where i am creating a dynamic form where user can create different field to make his or her own form.Then i want the application build their model dynamically based on the form fields.At the end database table will be created from that generated model and field value will be inserted as table data.Any suggestion or solution is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would shy away from trying to create the database table dynamically, but take an approach where you store the fields in a table, and relate them to a form object.  Something like this:

```
public Form
{
    [Key]
    public int FormId {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public IList<Field> {get;set;}
}

public Field
{
    [Key]
    public int FieldId {get;set;}
    public string FieldName {get;set;}
    public string FieldValue {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("FormId")]
    public Form Form {get;set;}
    public int FormId {get;set;}
}
```

With this structure, creating a form would simply be a case of creating a `Form` object, and then you can just simply add as many `Field` objects to it as you wish.  Each `Field` object can be named anything that you want, and would be unique to the `Form` it is associated to

Comment: How will we store form data? and form template?